# Install last CU for SP2 without installing SP1 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, service-pack

A client asked me to update their SQL Server.

It's an 2016 base release (13.00.1601.00)

Microsoft already released the SP2 CU10. I know that cumulative updates are... like... cumulative, but even between service packs?

I can jump and install directly SP2 CU10 or do I need to install the last CU for SP1 before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just install SP2 and then CU10. No need to install CU for SP1.

You can have a list of all SP + CU [here](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)

More relevant info :

If you have a large estate that needs to be patched, you can use dbatools - [Update-DbaInstance](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Update-DbaInstance)

Also, dbatools has a really nice - [build reference page](https://sqlcollaborative.github.io/builds)  that will tell you what the latest SP/CU is and End of support dates as well.